How can I show a pop-up for inputting a PIN in Laravel?
I am looking to create a pop-up when a user clicks on the "transfer" button in my application. It should ask the user to "Input PIN" and go through when a correct PIN is supplied. I am using Laravel and am not familiar with this.
